# Cрабатывает двойное нажатие

Tags: javascript, битрикс

В мобильной версии сайта в детальной странице для примера здесь https://xn--e1aofbbhkdf.xn--p1ai/catalog/khleb-i-khlebobulochnye-izdeliya/khleb/baget-solodovyy-150g/ при добавление товара в корзину увеличивается при каждом нажатии на две единицы. Как это можно исправить? Данная ошибка только в мобильной версии

На классы dec и inc вешается событие прибавления и отправки в корзину. Но вот почему два раза срабатывает не понимаю.

```js
var fieldCount = function (el) {
            var
                // Мин. значение
                min = el.data('min') || false,
                // Макс. значение
                max = el.data('max') || false,
                // Кнопка уменьшения кол-ва
                dec = el.siblings('.js-minus'),
                // Кнопка увеличения кол-ва
                inc = el.siblings('.js-plus'),

                inc2 = el.parents('.goods__item').find('.js-for-adults'),

                inc3 = el.parents('.stepper').find('.stepper__btn-plus'),

                dec2 = el.parents('.stepper').find('.stepper__btn-minus');

            el.addClass('inited');
```

Comment: покликал, добавляется по одной позиции

Comment: На мобильной версии?

Comment: да, в разных категориях

Comment: хотя погоди, нашел

Comment: Крч, там очень сложно понять по тому что ты скинул, поковырял верстку, у количества есть атрибут (data-ratio) со значением 1? ставлю 0.5. Прибавляется по единице. Скорее всего где то в значении атрибута нужно править. Потому что ставлю значение 2, прибавляет по 4. И так далее

Comment: Data-ratio никакого отношения к этому не имеет. Этот аттрибут отвечает за кратность товара. Например если надо покупать не по штучно, а по 0.5 кг к примеру. Здесь вся проблема что срабатывает дважды. Это видно через консоль, но пока не вижу где дважды прописывается событие. Но по тому что я прислал конечно трудно понять.

Comment: Проблема была в том что было два события при клике touchend и click

Comment: function init(el) {
            if (!el.attr('disabled')) {
                dec.on('touchend', decrement);
                inc.on('touchend', increment);
            } сделал так и теперь кликает на мобилке по одной единице